# Adding custom layer to packet from capture fails

Tags: go, gopacket

I am trying to implement my own decoding layer ontop of TCP, so far it only works when I create a packet without any Eth/IP/TCP header and set its layer to my custom layer manually. The data of the custom protocol is inside an ordinary TCP payload.

How do I decode only the payload of the TCP layer as another layer?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

var (
    pcapFile string = "capt.pcap"
    handle   *pcap.Handle
    err      error
)

type CustomLayer struct {
    SomeByte    byte
    AnotherByte byte
    restOfData  []byte
}

var CustomLayerType = gopacket.RegisterLayerType(
    2001,
    gopacket.LayerTypeMetadata{
        "CustomLayerType",
        gopacket.DecodeFunc(decodeCustomLayer),
    },
)

func (l CustomLayer) LayerType() gopacket.LayerType {
    return CustomLayerType
}

func (l CustomLayer) LayerContents() []byte {
    return []byte{l.SomeByte, l.AnotherByte}
}

func (l CustomLayer) LayerPayload() []byte {
    return l.restOfData
}

func decodeCustomLayer(data []byte, p gopacket.PacketBuilder) error {
    p.AddLayer(&CustomLayer{data[0], data[1], data[2:]})

    // nil means this is the last layer. No more decoding
    return nil
}

func main() {
    handle, err = pcap.OpenOffline(pcapFile)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer handle.Close()

    packetSource := gopacket.NewPacketSource(handle, handle.LinkType())
    for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
        tcpLayer := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeTCP)
        if tcpLayer != nil {
            fmt.Println("TCP layer detected.")
            tcp, _ := tcpLayer.(*layers.TCP)
            fmt.Println("Sequence number: ", tcp.Seq)
            customLayer := packet.Layer(CustomLayerType)
            if customLayer != nil { // always nil
                customLayerContent, _ := customLayer.(*CustomLayer)
                // Now we can access the elements of the custom struct
                fmt.Println("Payload: ", customLayerContent.LayerPayload())
                fmt.Println("SomeByte element:", customLayerContent.SomeByte)
                fmt.Println("AnotherByte element:", customLayerContent.AnotherByte)
            }
        }
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

Most of the code is from [this great post by devdungeon](https://www.devdungeon.com/content/packet-capture-injection-and-analysis-gopacket#custom-layers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As no one responded I am going to answer it myself now.

Basically we have 3 options to handle this:

1. Create an extended TCP layer that handles our additional bytes and override default one by setting `layers.LinkTypeMetadata[layers.LinkTypeTCP]` to our extended version. [Have a look at this example](http://damianzaremba.co.uk/2017/12/decoding-arista-ethertype-headers-with-gopacket/).
2. Create a new packet from the TCP payload using `gopacket.NewPacket` setting `firstLayerDecoder` to `CustomLayerType` and decode it normally.
3. As you mostly don't need an actual layer but instead a filled CustomLayer struct simply write a `DecodeBytesToCustomStruct` function where you pass TCP payload. This way we can even return multiple structs from one packets payload which wouldn't be possible otherwise.

Omit all CustomLayer code from above.

```
type CustomStruct struct {
    SomeByte    byte
    AnotherByte byte
    restOfData  []byte
}

func (customStruct *CustomStruct) DecodeStructFromBytes(data []byte) error { 
    customStruct.SomeByte = data[0]
    customStruct.AnotherByte = data[1]
    customStruct.restOfData = data[2:]
    return nil
}
```

In your main.go

```
for packet := range packetSource.Packets() {
    tcpLayer := packet.Layer(layers.LayerTypeTCP)
    if tcpLayer != nil {
        tcp, _ := tcpLayer.(*layers.TCP)
        if tcp.Payload != nil && len(tcpLayer.Payload) > 0 {
            customStruct := CustomStruct{}
            customStruct.DecodeStructFromBytes(tcp.Payload)
            fmt.Println("SomeByte element:", customStruct.SomeByte)
        }
    }
}
```

`tcp.Payload` is the same as `packet.ApplicationLayer().Payload()`

Comment: You went with the third option I guess. I'm learning GO and I'd like to understand better what's the good and bad of the three options. Thanks for the question/answer btw!